# Can a created segwit address match a non-segwit vanity address?

Tags: segregated-witness

For example, if I have the following vanity address: 1abcde.... as my current bitcoin address, is it possible to create the same vanity address for Segwit: 3abcde... ?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible. i can create such prorgam for you, but without GPU acceleration it will run too slow

Comment: So, it's not a straightforward import your old address and get a matching Segwit address I presume.